# Visual studio 2013 Premium - project templates packages versions

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Premium. When I create a new Web API project for example all packages are with old versions and need an update. Is there a way to set VS or NuGet maybe to create the new project with latest versions of the packages?

Answer (score 0):

No, templates packaged in Visual Studio define which versions of the package that they want to pick. A template is not guaranteed to work with the latest updates, since newer packages could have breaking changes. Hence, the onus is on the developer to update the package as they see fit.